# How do you create a subtask in Celery

Tags: python, celery

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/v2.2.6/userguide/tasksets.html

proj/

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from kombu import Exchange, Queue
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj',
             broker='redis://myredis.com',
             backend='redis://myredis.com',
             include=['proj.tasks'])

a_exchange = Exchange('a_ex', type='topic')

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
    CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS=True,
    CELERY_ROUTES = {"app.tasks.timeme": "a"}
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from proj.celery import app
import time

@app.task
def timeme(ts):
    print 'hi'
    lat = time.time() - float(ts)
    return (lat, time.time())
```

do_tasks.py

```
import proj.tasks
import time
import sys

stime = time.time()
while time.time() < stime + 15:
    res = proj.tasks.timeme.apply_async(args=[time.time()], link=proj.tasks.timeme())
```

when I run do_task.py, it's throwing me an error:

```
TypeError: timeme() takes exactly 1 argument(0 given)
```

I know there is some problem with `link` because it works fine if i dont specify `link`

My guess is that `timeme` have to be a subtask.
I am not sure how to specify timeme as a subtask.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put .`s()` afterwards

```
res = proj.tasks.timeme.apply_async(args=[time.time()], link=proj.tasks.timeme.s())
```